# People pickup workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, people-picker

I hv two lists,,
List A has text column which included e maril addresses
List B has a People pickup column

I want to create a workflow to copy e mails from list A to people pickup column in List B,
I tried to create a workflow but i failed , Hope your help

Answer (score 0):

Because text column and person or group column are not in the same type of information, person or group column only allows people and groups in the selection, so you cannot add email address in the person or group column through workflow.